How can I approximate an unknown function of $x$ and $y$ with polynomials?
Say I have an unknown function:
$$
f: (x,y) \to (u,v)
$$
and I know the values for $n$ point correspondences:
$$
(x_i,y_i) \to (u_i,v_i).
$$
If I assume a function form expressed with unknown parameters, I can use (non)linear minimization of the sum of squared errors to estimate the parameters.
A simple version of this is a linear transform:
$$
u = ax + by + c
$$
$$
v = dx + ey + f.
$$
However, I would like to use the polynomials: $\{1,x,x^2,y,y^2,xy\}$ to take into account nonlinear effects.
I suspect it may be better to use polynomials of a special form (e.g. Chebyshev polynomials). If so, why?
How do I solve the problem above with polynomials up to 2nd degree?
